# get plugin directory url

Tags: plugin-development, constants

I am trying to use SMOF Options Framework in a plugin and i have this problem.
SMOOF use this constants to get theme directory url:

```
if( !defined('ADMIN_PATH') )
    define( 'ADMIN_PATH', get_template_directory() . '/admin/' );
if( !defined('ADMIN_DIR') )
    define( 'ADMIN_DIR', get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin/' );
```

But i want to use SMOF in a plugin, not in theme, how can i get the plugin directory url? What to put in order to get_template_directory() and get_template_directory_uri() to use it in a plugin?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );` for the URL and `plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );` for the path.

Pass the plugin’s main file to both functions to get similar results.

Besides that, `ADMIN_PATH` and `ADMIN_DIR` are really poor names for custom code. They might result in collisions with other code in the future. Try to use better names, something with a unique prefix.

Comment: working like a charm to make local resource calls, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have created a [wordpress plugin](https://github.com/artworkarchive/aa_wp_plugin) that uses custom css/js code, in order to include these resources locally add a line like this one:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-aa-style', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'css/wp-aa-style.css',false,'1.1','all');
```

`wp-aa-style` is the element id make sure to define a `css folder` and a `wp-aa-style.css` file inside your WordPress plugin's main folder

Adding this answer hoping it will help someone willing to use `plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )` to make local resource calls (instead of static public URLs) for custom WordPress plugins.

Comment: I guess that your "demo" plugin is gone from GitHub... oh well. Thanks for the tip, anyway.