# How to use own css of functionality plugin?

Tags: plugin-development

I had built a functionality plugin and hooked with actions to another plugin. I had also made a style.css in myplugin/stylesheets/ directory. I placed the code there. I would like to make the styling dependent on my plugin and not my theme.

So far I have been trying this:

```
function epf_override_style() {
    wp_register_style( 'epf-style', '/stylesheets/style.css' ); //Subdir in plugin directory.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'epf-style' );
}

add_action( 'es_extra_bottom_info','epf_override_style' );
```

How can I use the stlye.css of my plugin instead of the theme's (child theme's) style.css?

Comment: You will need to show some code examples, what you have done to make this work, what errors you have - without seeing how you are doing it, it is not possible to offer workable solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. To be honest, I have done nothing so far, because I don't know how to start connecting.

Comment: But, you did "build a plugin" so, why not start by showing that - without additional information your question will be closed - because currently there is no way to answer it.

Comment: I updated my post. Thank you!

Comment: You need to use a function to get teh full path to the file, relative paths are not secure or reliable - look at questions like this - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/127860/get-plugin-directory-url

Comment: @QStudio Thank you very much. Good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I find working is this:

```
function epf_override_style() {

    wp_register_style( 'epf-style', '/wp-content/plugins/extended-plugin-functionality/stylesheets/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'epf-style' );
    
}

add_action( 'wp_print_styles','epf_override_style' );
```

I have found the solution here: https://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/wordpress/enhance-wordpress-plugins-css-javascript/

All the comments helped to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook [stylesheet_uri](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/stylesheet_uri/) which lets you override the URL to the active theme or child theme's style.css:

```
function epf_stylesheet_uri() {
    return plugins_url( '/stylesheets/style.css', __FILE__ );
}
add_filter( 'stylesheet_uri', 'epf_stylesheet_uri', 10, 1 );
```

This will then use your plugin's style.css instead of the theme's. But IMO if you want to override the style you should really be changing the theme instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately it doesn't work if I replace my code with yours.